# Disable chrome custom tabs?

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs

I recently got an update from chrome beta and it came with chrome custom tabs. 
I do not like this feature and would like to just open the links directly without pressing the open in chrome button.

Thanks

Comment: Chrome Custom Tabs has been a part of Chrome since v45. It's up to each application developer to decide if they want to open content in regular Chrome of in a Chrome Custom Tab. Maybe one of the applications you are using has been updated to use it?

Comment: @andreban so its not possible just to automatically open it as a chrome tab

Comment: You can find more info on how it works here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter

```
chrome://flags/#tab-management-experiment-type
```

and disable it. Restart and it's back to normal.

Comment: Prefect, I was just looking for this. Thanks.

Comment: This answer seems to no longer be current: https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/02/21/chrome-65-beta-removes-flag-opens-app-links-chrome-custom-tabs/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have worked for me:

1. Open Google application or do a search, click the hamburger in the top left and go into Settings.
2. Go into Accounts and privacy.
3. Turn off 'open web pages in app'.
4. This appears to turn off chrome custom tabs.

Comment: This only works for the Google app.  Other apps still open in custom tabs.